# Text is not transitioning in with parent element, it just pops up immediately

Tags: css, reactjs, reactstrap

I have a bar that pops up if the server responds with an error message.

For example, if they enter the wrong credentials to login, the bar will `transition: height 0.5s ease-in` with the error message from the server stating the credentials are incorrect.

With some help, I did get the bar transition to work. The issue I have now is the text renders before the transition is done so it looks pretty weird. Thought it would inherit the styles from the parent, but does not. Doesn't recognize the transition/animation.

Here is my component:

```
renderMessage() {
    const { errors } = this.props;

    if (errors) {
        return (
            <div 
                className={
                    errors
                    ?
                    'hide-error-message show-error-message'
                    :
                    'hide-error-message'
                }
            >
                <i 
                    onClick={ this.closeMessage } 
                    className='float-right fas fa-times'>
                </i>
                <div
                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: errors.non_field_errors[0] }}>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

render() {
    const { errors } = this.props;

    return (
        <div id='error-messages'>
            <div 
                className={ 
                    errors 
                    ? 
                    'hide-error-messages-bar show-error-messages-bar' 
                    : 
                    'hide-error-messages-bar' 
                }>
                <Container>{ this.renderMessage() }</Container>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here is the latest iteration of the Sass. Tried about 20 other things:

```
#error-messages {
    position: relative; 
    top: 105px;
    background-color: $croner-red;        
    color: #FFF;

    .hide-error-messages-bar {
        visibility: hidden;
        height: 0;
        transition: height 0.5s ease-out;        
    }

    .hide-error-messages-bar.show-error-messages-bar {
        visibility: visible;
        transition: height 0.5s ease-in;
        height: 65px;
        width: 100%;

        .hide-error-message {
            opacity: 0;
            height: 0;
            padding: 8px 0;
            transition: opacity 2s ease-in;                        
        }

        .hide-error-message.show-error-message {
            opacity: 1;

            i {
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch up the height transition for `transform: translateY()`. Since your notification bar is out of the flow and won't effect any other elements just move it up and down the Y access. You can keep the height of your div so that the text doesn't change and go all crazy.

Here is a codepen, toggle the class with the button https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oyZPJQ

```
   .hide-error-messages-bar {
        transform: translateY(-100vh);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-out;        
    }

    .hide-error-messages-bar.show-error-messages-bar {
        transform: translateY(5vh);
        width: 100%;
   }
```